# How to mock public void method using jmockit?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I am trying to write some junit test for my Spring MVC controller and so far I am able to do it successfully. I am using Spring Mock along with jmockit as well.

Below is my method in the `DataController` controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "processWork", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
DataResponse processWork(@RequestParam("conf") final String value, @RequestParam("dc") final String dc) {

    // .. some code here


    SomeOtherClass modifier = new SomeOtherClass(zookClient);
    List<Map<String, String>> mappings = getMappings(dc);
    modifier.processTask(value, mappings);      

    // .. some code here

}
```

Now in `SomeOtherClass`, `processTask` method is like this -

```
public void processTask(String value, List<Map<String, String>> mappings) throws Exception {

    //  some code here

}
```

Below is my junit test which I wrote for the `processWork` method in the `DataController` class.

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void test03_processWork() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(
        get("/processWork").param("conf", "shsysysys").param("dc", "eux")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now the problem with this is, whenever I am running `test03_processWork` unit test, it goes into `processWork` method of my controller (which is fine) and then it calls `processTask` method of my `SomeOtherClass` and that is what I want to avoid.

Meaning, is there any way, I can mock `processTask` method of `SomeOtherClass` to return some default value, instead of running actual code what is there in `processTask` method?

Currently with my junit test run, it is also calling `processTask` method of `SomeOtherClass` and the code inside `processTask` is also running and that's what I want to avoid. I don't want any of the code which is there in `processTask` to run by mocking using jmockit?

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain what is wrong? I am happy to improve my question if there are any mistakes from me. I am still learning on mocking stuff.

Comment: Please see MockUp<>  examples at http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/AnExample.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JMockit](http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.in/2012/06/jmockit-tutoriallearn-it-today-with.html#public_methods) to mock your `public void` method like this:

```
new MockUp<SomeOtherClass>() {
    @Mock
    public void processTask(String value, List<Map<String, String>> mappings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
};
```

Just add it above the mock at the starting of your unit test.

Comment: Given a class with 3 methods of which 1 is void returning method, I mock the other 2 with Expectations. I see for void returning method alone I cannot use MockUp as both can't be used in 1 test case. What's the way to achieve this?